# Real Analysis: ε-δ definition to prove that f is a continuous function.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:R\backslash \{1 \} \to R$ be defined by $f(x)= \frac{1}{(1-x)}$. Use the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition to prove that $f$ is a continuous function.

My attempt is 
let $c \in R \backslash \{1\}$. $$|f(x) - f(c)| = \Big|\frac{1}{1-x} - \frac{1}{1-c}\Big| = \Big|\frac{1}{1-x}\Big| \cdot \Big|\frac{1}{1-c}\Big| \cdot |x-c|$$ (this is the part I do not know how to simplify.)

Given $\epsilon > 0$, we choose $\delta =$ something I do not know. Then | something I do not know | $< \delta$ implies that $|f(x) - f(c)|$ something in the middle that I do not know $= \epsilon$.

Could someone please check my direction for the proof? If it is right, could you help me with the parts that I said I do not know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $c \neq 1$, and choose $\epsilon>0$.

Choose $\delta = \min(\frac{1}{2}|1-c|, \frac{1}{2}|1-c|^2 \epsilon) $.

Then if $|x-c|< \delta$, we have $|x-1| \ge |1-c|-|x-c| \ge \frac{1}{2} |1-c|$.

We also have $|f(x)-f(c)| = \frac{|x-c|}{|x-1||1-c|} \le \frac{2|x-c|}{|c-1|^2} < \epsilon$.

Comment: What allows you to do the following steps $|x-1| \ge |1-c|-|x-c| \ge \frac{1}{2} |1-c|$?

How do you go from the second step to the third step $|f(x)-f(c)| = \frac{|x-c|}{|x-1||1-c|} \le \frac{2|x-c|}{|c-1|^2} < \epsilon$?

Comment: The triangle inequality gives $|1-c| \le |x-1|+||x-c|$. The rest is just replacing $|x-1|$ by the lower bound and noting that $|x-c| < \delta$.

Comment: How do you go from second second part to the third part $|x-1| \ge |1-c|-|x-c| \ge \frac{1}{2} |1-c|$?

Comment: By choice, $|x-c| < \delta \le \frac{1}{2}|1-c|$, so you have $|x-1| \ge |1-c| - \frac{1}{2} |1-c|$.